# Replacing mingw g++ with MS cl.exe in makefile

Tags: c++, visual-c++, makefile, cl

I am trying to take a makefile that was written for mingw on Windows, and swap in cl.exe as the compiler. I removed the cflags that were GCC specific and replaced .o with .obj. I have not change the rules at all, so I don't know if that should be a problem.

I get the following error...

```
cl /link build/WavFileTool.obj src/WavFileTool.cpp
process_begin: CreateProcess(NULL, cl /link build/WavFileTool.obj src/WavFileTool.cpp, ...) failed.
make (e=2): The system cannot find the file specified.
```

And here is my makefile

```
CC := cl
CFLAGS := /link
BIN_DIR := bin
BUILD_DIR := build
SRC_DIR := src
MAIN := WavFileTool
TARGET := wavfiletool.exe
SOURCES := $(wildcard src/*.cpp)
OBJECTS := $(SOURCES:$(SRC_DIR)/%.cpp=$(BUILD_DIR)/%.obj)

$(BIN_DIR)/$(TARGET): CREATE_DIRS $(BUILD_DIR)/$(MAIN).obj $(OBJECTS) 
    $(CC) $(OBJECTS) $@ 

$(BUILD_DIR)/$(MAIN).obj: $(SRC_DIR)/WavFileTool.cpp
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $@ $<

$(BUILD_DIR)/%.obj: $(SRC_DIR)/%.cpp $(SRC_DIR)/%.h
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $@ $<

CREATE_DIRS: 
    if not exist $(BIN_DIR) mkdir $(BIN_DIR)
    if not exist $(BUILD_DIR) mkdir $(BUILD_DIR)

CLEAN:
    if exist $(BUILD_DIR) rmdir /Q /S $(BUILD_DIR)
```

Answer (score 0):

Some issues with the makefile as posted:

- CFLAGS should be '/c' not '/link';
- the MS toolchain uses link.exe for linking, not $(CC);
- both cl.exe and link.exe require a switch to specify the output file.

There is a less obvious problem as well. Since you seem to be using the mingw 'make' chances are that there might be a 'link.exe' in the same directory with 'make.exe'. Simply running 'link' from the makefile would execute the mingw 'link.exe' rather than the MS one. To direct 'make' to use the MS 'link' you need to provide a full path, which can generally be inferred from the environment e.g. '$(VCINSTALLDIR)\bin\link.exe'.

Below is the makefile with the necessary changes.

```
CC := cl
CFLAGS := /c
BIN_DIR := bin
BUILD_DIR := build
SRC_DIR := src
MAIN := WavFileTool
TARGET := wavfiletool.exe
SOURCES := $(wildcard src/*.cpp)
OBJECTS := $(SOURCES:$(SRC_DIR)/%.cpp=$(BUILD_DIR)/%.obj)

$(BIN_DIR)/$(TARGET): CREATE_DIRS $(BUILD_DIR)/$(MAIN).obj $(OBJECTS)
    $(VCINSTALLDIR)/bin/link /out:$@ $(OBJECTS)

$(BUILD_DIR)/$(MAIN).obj: $(SRC_DIR)/WavFileTool.cpp
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) /Fo$@ $<

$(BUILD_DIR)/%.obj: $(SRC_DIR)/%.cpp $(SRC_DIR)/%.h
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) /Fo$@ $<

CREATE_DIRS:
    if not exist $(BIN_DIR) mkdir $(BIN_DIR)
    if not exist $(BUILD_DIR) mkdir $(BUILD_DIR)

CLEAN:
    if exist $(BUILD_DIR) rmdir /Q /S $(BUILD_DIR)
```

See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/19z1t1wy.aspx for the full CL syntax (the link goes to the VC++ 2015 version, but you can select other versions on the page), and https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y0zzbyt4.aspx for LINK.

Comment: Same error still persists after adding your change.

Comment: I updated the answer to also correct CFLAGS and the link command, which I missed the first time around.